# Does alcohol hydrogen in the enol tautomer of a β-dicarbonyl have sp² character?

Tags: organic-chemistry, hybridization, carbonyl-compounds, hydrogen-bond

My reasoning for the somewhat implausible "$\mathrm{sp^2}$" character of the hydrogen between these two oxygens on the enol structure of the right comes from recognizing that if it were, then we would have 6 $\mathrm{sp^2}$ atoms with 6 π-electrons, so maybe that extra bit of instability from having a higher orbital on hydrogen could be sort of taken care of by being stable like an aromatic compound and forming a hydrogen bond.

So how could I go about figuring out if this is true, either with MO theory or something else?

> [image: dicarbonyl]

<sub>(source: [ucdavis.edu](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/@api/deki/files/2937/image011.png?revision=1))</sub>

Comment: So are you asking whether the hydrogen $2p$ orbitals are involved in bonding?

Comment: Yes, I think so, or if they are occupied ever, for instance would I expect this compound to experience a chemical shift when put into a magnetic field similar to an aromatic compound.

Comment: Not a chance. 2p are just too far away. Look at the energy levels diagram.

Comment: As @IvanNeretin points out, the hydrogen is s-hybridized like normal.  This $\ce{O..H..O}$ structure is just another example of a 3-center-2-electron bond involving hydrogen.  Diborane ($\ce{B2H6}$) is another example.  See [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29000/which-carbocation-is-more-stable-the-ethyl-or-1-propyl-carbocation/31729#31729), and links therein, for more information on such bonds involving hydrogen.

Comment: In reference to the possibility of downfield NMR shifts, the [C-13](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_frame_disp.cgi?spectrum_type=cnmr&amp;sdbsno=1030) and [H-1](http://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/direct_frame_top.cgi) spectra from SDBS show no signs of aromaticity.

Comment: Wait a minute. Diborane is electron-deficient, but this thing is not. See, we had a normal 2-electron O-H bond, then another O went in with its lone pair (2 more electrons). If anything, this should be a 3-center-4-electron construction.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, I agree, I should have written "3-center-4-electron" in my earlier comment.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Yes, it has 3c-4e character, but it is limited, as here's asymmetric h-bond - one of contributors much more dominating