# Dependence of carbocation stability with respect to the length of alkyl group

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, carbocation

- Which carbocation is more stable, the ethyl carbocation or n-propyl carbocation?
- What is the effect of alkyl group length on the stability of a carbocation?

Comment: Your first question, which carbocation is more stable, ethyl or n-propyl, has already been answered (see [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29000/which-carbocation-is-more-stable-the-ethyl-or-1-propyl-carbocation/31729#31729)).

Comment: @ron actually i couldn't completely understand the answer (quite a high level for me).But what i found from your answer is ethyl cation is an exception right?.But i have a doubt,is it correct that only methyl group can show inductive effect (can -CH2- group show inductive effect?)?Also would you post a simple answer about the dependence on length of alkyl group.

Comment: Yes $\ce{-CH2 -}$ can show an inductive effect, all alkyl groups can.

Comment: @ron thanks.Would you please explain me the dependence of +i effect on length?Is there any dependency?Am I wrong about this concept?

Comment: There is likely a measurable difference between methyl and ethyl due to the hyperconjugation reasons mentioned in the answer below. Beyond that I would expect very small differences (for example between n-propyl and ethyl).

Comment: So what you are saying is that +I effect of pentyl group and hexyl group will be having less difference.right?

Comment: Also how will we explain the variation in pka of acetic acid and propanoic acid with respect to +i effect? pka value:<http://crab.rutgers.edu/~alroche/Ch20.pdf>

Answer (score 2):

Carbocation stability is widely known to increase going from primary -> secondary -> tertiary.

[image]

In the absence of other factors (such as lone pair donation etc.), the major contribution to the greater stability of tertiary carbocations vs primary is due to **hyperconjugation** between the vacant p-orbital (carbocation) and the C-H sigma bonding MO's.

[image]

Based on hyper conjugation alone, you can predict that length of the alkyl chain will have no effect on the stability by itself, only the number of neighbouring C-H bonds with which hyper conjugation can take place.

In specific regard to ethyl vs n-propyl cation, neither are considered *stable*.

Comment: Then why is there a variation in the acidity of primary aliphatic acids say between hexanoic acid and butanoic acid ?though the ka value difference is small still what is the reason for the differencce?