# Which of these chlorides is more reactive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stability, reference-request, nucleophilic-substitution

We do learn that for $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reaction the rates are tertiary > secondary > primary > methyl. The reasons mentioned are usually inductive and hyper-conjugative effect.

But which of the effects is more dominant? So, let's take two chlorides, ethyl chloride and isobutyl chloride, which will be more reactive to $\mathrm{S_N1}$? If we refer to inductive effect, then isobutyl chloride should be more reactive. But if we refer to hyper-conjugation, then ethyl chloride should be more reactive.

Which is more reactive actually?

Note: [Which carbocation is more stable, the ethyl- or 1-propyl-carbocation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29000/which-carbocation-is-more-stable-the-ethyl-or-1-propyl-carbocation) is not the same as this as I am not satisfied with the answer there. That question compares the stability of carbocation while I am comparing the reaction rates which may depend on kinetic factors too. Actual data could be helpful.

Also, the isobutyl cation rearranges to a tertiary cation. Does the stability of rearranged carbocation affect the rate of reactivity?

Comment: I’m have been told that it follows this order , aromaticity>Electromeric effect>resonance >hyperconjugation>Inductive effect

Comment: I fully expect to receive some complaints about closing a question as a duplicate of another question without answers, but I see no point in keeping two copies of exactly the same question. If anybody still wants to complain, please bring it to meta.

Comment: @orthocresol my question was asked 1 hour before that